# How to find the location by using the phone mac address?

Tags: html, google-maps, geolocation

How to find the current location based on the phone mac address or gps or tower locaiton by using the google map.

Please let me know if have any html code sample

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use watch my location API and it will help to get the current location every sec. You just store one place(server) and get from the longitude in another location.

```
var id, target, options;

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  if (target.latitude === crd.latitude && target.longitude === crd.longitude) {
    console.log('Congratulations, you reached the target');
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
  }
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

target = {
  latitude : 0,
  longitude: 0,
}

options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Geolocation API** supported by HTML5

> The HTML Geolocation API is used to get the geographical position of a
>   user. Since this can compromise user privacy, the position is not
>   available unless the user approves it.

Try the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to get your position.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<div id="mapholder"></div>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;

    var img_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
    +latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
    document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML = "<img src='"+img_url+"'>";
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got this error: User denied the request for Geolocation.

How to make approve? where should i give the phone number?

Comment: When your browser asks for the permission to use your device's location, click on approve.

Comment: I jsut copy paste in notepad and save as html. it is not asking the denny allo pop. but this is not i am requested. I want to track some other person based on the mac address or phone number like that. how to do that.

Comment: Security restrictions in Chrome does not allow using geolocation from a file:/// URI. Try it on IE or Firefox.

Comment: You have shared like http://html5doctor.com/demos/geolocation/geolocation-watchposition-example.html

Comment: But i need mobile phone tracking feature. it is kind of gps track feature.

Comment: @Lemon If you want mobile phone tracking feature, then you need to create an app/service which runs continuously on the subject device(with gps enabled all the time) which will track and send his current location info in response. What you are asking is too-broad and won't be covered by the html code sample.

Comment: I am not expect complete solution. If you know any third party tool for this feature, let me know i will integrate.